# How do I migrate an existing web app on heroku to rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migrate

I have an app written in Play framework but I would like to rewrite it to rails. How this should be done? I am thinking of removing old app from git, setting up a new rails app and generate models from existing database. But I wouldnt be able update app until I finish the rewrite.

Edit. this is my first rails app, so an answer with more detail wouldnt hurt ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat your rails app as a brand new project, a new git repository and a new Heroku App.  So

1. Create your rails app in a new directory (not a sub-directory of the Play framework project)
2. In your rails app directory, create a new git repository
3. In your rails app directory, create a new heroku application

Assuming your data model is really going to be the same, either backup and restore your database to a new instance (if its an Heroku Posgres database you can create a fork) and connect your rails app to the new database instance.

This approach keeps a working copy of your existing project (just in case you change your mind).  It also doesn’t pollute your new ruby project with irrelevant Java code, making your ruby project easier to understand from the git history.